# While i am creating a simple maven springboot project i am getting this error

Tags: mysql, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-mvc

ArtifactTransferException: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:3.3.0 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.3.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.3.0.pom
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

i tried adding dependency but that too was not much use

Comment: you could share your pom.xml
also try `mvn clean package -U`